# How to use the event driven SAX(Simple API FOR XML) parser in C# or is it better to use System.XML namespace?

Tags: c#, event-handling, sax, saxparser, xml-parsing

In C++ we can import msxml DLL to our application and then implement the methods of the interface ISAXContentHandler in a class of our application. Later create an ISAXReader object and invoke the contentHandler with the instance of this class where we have given the implemnatation for the eventhandler interfaces.
      Similiarly I want to achieve the same thing in C#. Is there any way to do this in C#?? I mean is there any way to have eventbased SAX parsing in C#. 
            There is one more method I thought would help me in achieving parsing the XML documant and getting the XML information to my application. 
  I followed the link   "**http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/xml/article.php/c4221**"

Here DOM is used and System.XML namespace is being used. 
Can anyone kindly help me with this regard,----**What is the way  to achieve Event driven XML parsing in C#**
 **or should I use System.XML namespace (DOM).   if there exists a SAX event driven way plz let me know how to do it in C#**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest you get to a SAX-reader in the .Net framework is the [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) class. It is not event based, but it allows you to iterate through the document in a similar manner. Look at this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read.aspx

If you need maximum performance then the XmlReader is a good choice, but there are other alternatives that offer a more friendly api. The [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class allows you to treat the xml document as a hierarchical tree, while the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) allows you to use LINQ to parse the xml. Which one you need depends on which model you are comfortable with and your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem some time ago.  While I can't answer which is better, the already implemented System.XML DOM or a C# SAX parser (this really depends on your application), I can tell you that it is indeed possible to implement a SAX parser in C#.

In fact, it has already been done by Martin Friedrich at CodeProject: [Towards a Declarative SAX Framework : Part 1 - A Simple SAX-to-C#-Mapping](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/declsaxfwork.aspx).